# Indy FTP Client rising error, after trying to start another upload?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

```
IdFTP: TIdFTP;
...
procedure TForm1.IdFTPWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
   IdFTP.Disconnect;

   try

      IdFTP.Connect;

      IdFTP.ChangeDir( directory );
      IdFTP.Put( fileName, ExtractFileName( fileName ) );

   except

   end;

end;
```

This is most of the code.
I wish when the 1 upload complete to start another, but this code seems to rise an error 10048.

- is it correct way to upload sequence of files and commands to the server ?
- why this error 10048 is rising, and how to fix it ?

Comment: How do you configure which server and port to connect to? How do you configure username and password? Active vs passive? Binmode vs ascii? What does `i` ever do for you? There isn't much code here, it feels like there ought to be more somewhere that would have the bug.

Comment: i - left from other piece of code inside the procedure. ( removed ). the server is connected on port 21, transfertype is binary, active mode, it is configured to accept all connections - anonymous mode.

Comment: the thing hapend in onWorkEnd procedure of IdFTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 10048 = Socket already in use: [info](http://www.indyproject.org/KB/index.html?lprrshaddressalreadyinuse.htm)

You don't need the WorkEnd event, Put statement returns when its finished with uploading a file:

```
  // loop
  for I := 0 to files.Count-1 do
  begin
    idFtp1.Connect;
    idFtp1.Put(files[i]);
    idFtp1.Disconnect;
  end;

  // or
  idFtp1.Put('MyFirstFile');
  idFtp1.DisConnect;
  // ......
  idFtp1.Connect;
  idFtp1.ChangeDir('DirSecondFile');
  idFtp1.Put('MySecondFile');
```

Comment: this will do aswell, but is there a way to do it the way i tried - after each uploaded file to have some sort of disconnecting and reconnecting ?

Answer (score 4):

DO NOT use the `OnWork...` events to drive your business logic! They are meant for status only. For the most part, Indy is NOT event driven, minus a few exceptions.

In this case, `OnWorkEnd` triggers after the raw file data has been transmitted but BEFORE the server's response to the upload has been received and processed. The correct way to upload another file is to simply call `Put()` again after the previous call to `Put()` exits, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.UploadFiles;
begin
  try
    IdFTP.Connect;
    try
      while (there is a file to upload) do
      begin
        if (directory is different than current) then
          IdFTP.ChangeDir(directory);
        IdFTP.Put(fileName, ExtractFileName(fileName));
      end;
    finally
      IdFTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: another great example. thank you very very much Remy Leaeau aswel :) Your comment is greath and noted :)